# How do I install PDO and GD for php-cgi

Tags: php-cgi

I have PHP 5.3.6 and I use ubuntu.

How can I enable/install PDO and GD Extensions. I have already tried installing `php5-mysql` and `php5-gd`. I have also tried adding this into my php.ini:

```
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=gd.so
```

Comment: Did you install `php-cgi` from the standard repositories?  If so, then it should have just worked.  Which `php.ini` did you check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you should be needing to do is:

`apt-get install php5-gd php5-mysql`

You should not need to edit anything else,  This should cause the `extension=` stuff to be added to /etc/php5/conf.d files which will automatically be included.

Check the output of the `phpinfo()` function to see if the modules are enabled or not.  Note that although you shouldn't need to edit them, there are separate php.ini files for apache2/cli/cgi in, for example, `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

If your /etc/php5/conf.d directory is empty, and those packages are already installed, someone must have deleted files from there, in order to get apt to restore them, run:

```
apt-get -o DPkg::Options::='--force-confmiss' reinstall php5-gd php5-mysql
```

The reason you'd have to do this, is that dpkg assumes that if you deleted conffiles, you did it for a reason, and it doesn't want to revert your change.

Comment: I use nginx. The /etc/php5/conf.d directory is empty.

Answer (score 0):

install `php5-dev` and `php-pear`, then you should be able to install pdo_mysql via `pecl install pdo_mysql`.
The lines in php.ini should be added automatically.

Comment: That shouldn't be needed for 5.3.6.  PDO should be part of the the standard php-mysql package.